# How to use Ubuntu as a guest OS in Virtual Box full screen

Tags: unity, virtualbox, guest-additions, 16.10

I've installed Ubuntu 16.10 as a guest VM in VirtualBox. I have installed the guest additions and rebooted. When I put VirtualBox into full screen mode the background does not resize and the unity launcher is not drawn properly.
[image]
I've used Lubuntu and Xubuntu in the past and they worked fine in fullscreen. Also, the lockscreen works correctly. Is this a known problem with Ubuntu/Unity itself or should I expect it to work?

Details:

- Host OS Windows 10 64-bit
- VirtualBox 5.1.6
- Guest additions installed from the 'Guest Additions CD' in VirtualBox

**edit** further information - it's the resizing that doesn't work, it seems like it's only OK if you stick to whatever screen size it was when you logged in (for example if I get something like the current screen I can log out and back in and it fixes itself)

Comment: When you installed guest additions, did you "auto-install" it when you inserted the GA CD, or did you manually execute the sh file? You're not running the Unity8 login, are you? It's probably that guest additions haven't been updated for 16.10. Cheers, Al

Comment: I think I did 'autorun' the CD. I don't think it's unity 8, I don't remember being asked either way. This is the 1st time I've tried Ubuntu for years...  Anyway, that's a good point, I can wait for the next update of the GAs.

Comment: Reinstall GA using the .sh file, and make sure that at your login prompt, you haven't selected the Unity8 environment, just the Ubuntu environment. Cheers, Al

Comment: Hi Al, reinstalling didn't change anything unfortunately. I confirmed it's not Unity 8. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I installed 16.10 into Virtualbox 5.1 and had the same problem. No workaround. Although apps like Nautilus file manager, and Firefox, were able to maximize to the full screen size. I guess we'll just have to wait for new guest additions. Cheers, Al